# OpenCV Rect conventions – What is x, y, width, height?

Tags: javascript, python, c++, opencv

I'm studying the [OpenCV tutorial found here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/def/tutorial_js_meanshift.html). I am a little confused about what is represented in the following line of code:

```
let trackWindow = new cv.Rect(150, 60, 63, 125);
```

I'm not sure what the convention is with regards to what exactly is represented by x, y, width, height in this case. I made a drawing showing what I think it is. Could you please let me know if my understanding is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The convention is as follows, it is x,y,w,h as you said, x,y are the coordinates for the top left corner of the box, and w,h are just the width and height, that's it, and similarily the origin of the image is from the top left, not bottom left, as specified by your drawing

Here is a diagram to better illustrate this

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. will accept answer in 6 mins as soon as StackOverflow allows me.